# Is "that had been" omitted here?

Tags: ellipsis, reduced-relative-clauses

> Among the biggest changes prompted by the scandal was political morality.

Is this omitted here?

> Among the biggest changes ***that had been*** prompted by the scandal was political morality.

Comment: I think your understanding of the sentence is mostly correct, but what was the context of the sentence?  Context is very important to full understanding of something.

Comment: You can add a _that had been_ if you want to, but the sentence is grammatical either way, and both versions have the same meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Many quite distinguished grammarians agree with your analysis: they call postposed modifiers like *prompted by the scandal*  "reduced relative clauses", where the reduction is accomplished by ["Whiz-deletion"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/24489).

This analysis certainly results in an understandable *paraphrase* of the original utterance; but I myself do not believe that the construction is actually a result of reducing an underlying relative clause. I think the “rule” at work here is

> A modifying phrase whose head is followed by additional elements must be placed *after* the modified element.

For instance, we speak of *a grateful man* and *a very grateful man*, but not ∗*a grateful for help man*; this modifying phrase must be postposed: *a man grateful for help*.

The rule seems to be based on our left-to-right parsing conventions: we prefer to arrange our utterances so each word signals what kind of term will follow. Modifiers before a head provide this signal, but modifiers after a head are ‘digressions’; it requires a little extra effort to pin down where the phrase ends.

Modifiers typically affected by this rule are

- participle phrases, because a participle in its ‘verb’-al aspect often takes postposed complements and adjuncts. Your *prompted by the scandal* is an example.
- preposition phrases, because a preposition is the head of the phrase and is usually followed by an object. Your *by the scandal* is an example—we do not say ∗*by the scandal prompted*.
- adjectives taking complements, like *grateful for help* above.

There are exceptions to this rule, such as *ready-to-wear*, *off-the-cuff*—but note that in writing we hyphenate such phrases, to overcome the parsing difficulty. Some, however, are so frequently used that they have ‘hardened’ into single words—*inline*, *online*, *offline* are some recent examples.

Comment: Additionally, if you treat the original model as an example of omission, there is no telling *what* was omitted.  Candidates include "that had been", "that has been", "that were" and "that are".  You'd be forced to make a choice about information that is simply not present in the original.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan Quite so. Moreover, any of those *that*s could be *which*.